# Spring role-based authorization VS ACL?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

i just want to know the difference between using **ACL** and spring **role-based authorization** in spring security 3 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ACL are privileges defined for an specific entity. And role based authorization are global privileges.

For example, with ACLs you can define that a specific user can modifiy a entity X (for example a file) but not an other entity.

Without ACLs you can only define that a user can modify all or none entity (of a specific type).

So ACLs support entity related fine grained privileges.